# Rogue dual wielding plus Cunning action

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue

So I was wondering I'm a level six rogue and I dual wield two short swords. Can I dash with Cunning action, attack with with my normal action, then attack with my off hand weapon since I have Dual Wielding?

Comment: By "I have Dual Wielding", do you mean that you have the Dual Wielder feat from the PHB?

Answer (score 14):

### No, you only have one Bonus Action a round.

Using your cunning action to Dash uses your Bonus Action.  Attacking with your off hand weapon also takes a Bonus Action.  Only one Bonus action per round so you would have to choose which you wanted to do.

The Feat Dual Wielding allows you to use two non-light weapons, but it still takes a Bonus Action to make the attack.

Comment: So if I just move without dashing could I but with both weapon?

Comment: @NickParker You can always move, take an action, and take a bonus action if you have an appropriate one, so yes, you can move, take your normal attack(s), then use a bonus action to attack off-handed.  The normal strategy for rogues is to dual-wield because they don't care about weapon damage, just sneak attack damage, which can only happen once per round.  Make your regular attack, then if you miss, use your bonus to try again, or if you hit, use your Cunning Action to disengage, dash away, or dodge, depending on the situation.

Comment: Small clarification @DarthPseudonym: I assume you meant "Hide" rather than "dodge." But otherwise, I totally agree.

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme Not really, hiding isn't usually relevant when you just knifed a guy -- I just mis-remembered which actions were covered by Cunning Action.